Adic spaces vs Berkovich for $\mathbb{Z}_p$
I always thought that adic spaces are just as powerful as Berkovich and their spectrum are just as rich.
However, for $\mathbb{Z}_p$, the Berkovich spectrum is the correct one; an interval.
However the adic $(\mathbb{Z}_p, \mathbb{Z}_p)$ or $(\mathbb{Z}_p, 0)$ will just give two points.
Is there a way to fix the adic one to also be a line, or is it not good for Archimedean purposes? Maybe we shouldn't be dividing the isomorphism classes of valuations?

What is the second element of your tuple? Is it ideal of definition? Ring of integral elements?

@AlexMathers it was the integral element, but your answer was very good

I don't think your interpretation of the Berkovich spectrum of $\mathbb Z_p$ is correct. The exact wording can vary but the Berkovich spectrum is something like
$$\mathcal M(A)=\{\text{multiplicative seminorms $|\cdot|:A\to\mathbb{R}^{\geqslant0}$ such that $|\cdot|\leqslant |\cdot|_A$}\}.$$
Now we consider this for $A=\mathbb{Z_p}$ with the usual $p$-adic absolute value. A given multiplicative seminorm $|\cdot|$ must send any units to $1$ by multiplicativity, and then after that you have two options: $(1)$ $|p|=0$, and then $|x|=0$ for all $x$, or $(2)$ $|p|\neq0$, and then the value at any element of $\mathbb Z_p$ is determined by $|p^nu|=|p|^n$.
So the multiplicative seminorm in summary is determined by $|p|$ which due to the restriction $|p|\leqslant|p|_{\mathbb Z_p}=p^{-1}$ means that the choice is basically to choose $|p|\in[0,p^{-1}]$. Any nonzero choice here gives basically the same multiplicative seminorm (I don't know whether the Berkovich spectrum cares about "equivalence" the way the adic spectrum does...)
Anyways, to address another point of your question, the adic spectrum is inherently a mismatch for the Archimedean world. Part of the conditions on the rings is that we have an open subring of $A$ which carries the $I$-adic topology for an ideal $I$. A direct consequence of this result is that the subgroups $\{I^n\}$ are a system of neighborhoods consisting of open subgroups, and this condition is basically the topological-algebraic version of the strong triangle inequality $\|a+b\|\leqslant\max(\|a\|,\|b\|)$; Archimedean things will never satisfy it.
We don't expect in this realm (similar with algebraic geometry) for $\operatorname{Spa} \mathbb Z_p$ (let's ignore the ring of definition for a moment) to be a line. We expect $\operatorname{Spa}\mathbb Q_p$ to be a point, and we expect $\operatorname{Spa}\mathbb Z_p$ to be some integral thing with generic fiber the point $\operatorname{Spa}\mathbb Q_p$ and special fiber $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb F_p$ or something like this. If we want the "interval" in one dimension we take $\operatorname{Spa}\mathbb Q_p\langle T\rangle$, just as one takes $\operatorname{Spec}k[T]$ to get a line in algebraic geometry.

Thanks for the answer. I meant that $Spec(Z_p)$ should be a interval by forgetting some structure on the 3-manifold analogy (if $Spec(Z_p)$ is a filled donut with circle $F_p$ inside, you can project a point in the donut to its distance from the circle, which is what the berkovich is showing). That's why I find the adic-definition of identifying equivalent norms weird.
